# View published content to anonymous users front page only

Tags: nodes

I have the *Content access* module installed, but it's not good for sorting this. I just want to make it so deny access is not denied on frontpage.

In permissions I have de-selected view publish content for anonymous users, but how can I make it so they can view the front page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as they don't have permission to view content, and as long as your template file(s) say `print render($page['content'])` then they should be denied access.

However, you *could* do something like this:

1. Make a custom template file called `page--front.tpl.php` inside your theme's folder
2. Copy the contents of `page.tpl.php` to that file
3. Alter the new `page--front.tpl.php` file so that it either doesn't render any content anywhere (including the sidebars), or make it so it only renders the content to logged in users.

Example:

```
<?php if (user_is_anonymous()): ?>
  <?php print t('Hello. This is where you would normally see content.'); ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```